# Removing index.php from url works on localhost and doesn't work online

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

I work on PHP project using codeigniter, I remove the index.php from URL locally, here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

When I upload the project online routes don't work at all, and I need to set index.php with plain url instead of the route!

for example instead of writing `index` I have to write
 `index.php/product_management_controller/index`

If I write index it doesn't work even if I update the route to include index.php !! That means the routes are also not working!

my current route is 
`$route['index'] = "product_management_controller/index";`

And here's a few things I've set in my config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

What is the solution!!

It works properly locally!!

Answer (score 0):

Your server that your hosting on will need to allow `.htaccess` files, in your Apache config you will need to add:

`AllowOverride All`

to your Apache config. Then restart the Apache server.

You could also try

`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]`

Comment: I host a server from godaddy, do I have access to the Appache config file ??

Comment: Is it a VPS or shared hosting?

Comment: I don't know actually, I go to godaddy then hosting and book a server from there!

Comment: Check my answer, I have added some to it. If you dont know your prbably on shared and they probably already have AllowOverrides on try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` to the top of your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

There is an documentation for removing index.php from url on codeigniter
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

By the way you are on godaddy shared server as per the comments and you don't have access to apache config file, but the good news is you don't need to worry rewrite mode is on for you by default. :)